# Как протестировать работу с текущей датой?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit

У меня есть код который переводит из одного вида дат в другую.

Из `"28 мар 17, 14:29"` в `Timestamp`

Из `"сегодня, 14:41"` в `Timestamp`

Из `"вчера, 14:41"` в `Timestamp`

```
public class TimeConverter {
    /**
     * Formatter for types "28 мар 17, 14:29".
     */
    final private SimpleDateFormat format;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    TimeConverter() {
        this.format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm");
    }

    /**
     * Converting datetime in Timestamp.
     * @param data for converting.
     * @return same datetime how Timestamp object.
     * @throws ParseException if the beginning of the specified string
     *            cannot be parsed.
     */
    Timestamp convert(final String data) throws ParseException {

        if (data.contains("сегодня")) return this.todayConverter(data);

        if (data.contains("вчера")) return this.yesterdayConverter(data);


        return new Timestamp(this.format.parse(data).getTime());
    }

    /**
     * Converter for types how : "сегодня, 14:41".
     * @param data String value for convert.
     * @return datetime how Timestamp object.
     */
    private Timestamp todayConverter(final String data) {

        final String[] time = getTime(data);

        final Calendar current = new GregorianCalendar();

        current.set(
                current.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                current.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                parseInt(time[0]),
                parseInt(time[1]));


        return new Timestamp(current.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    /**
     * Converter for types how : "вчера, 14:41".
     * @param data String value for convert.
     * @return datetime how Timestamp object.
     */
    private Timestamp yesterdayConverter(final String data) {

        return new Timestamp(todayConverter(data).getTime() - 86_400_000L);

    }

    /**
     * Get time from string with time and data.
     * @param data for parse.
     * @return array where by 0 index = hours, by 1 index = minutes.
     */
    private String[] getTime(final String data) {

        final String[] arr = data.split(" ");

        return arr[1].split(":");
    }
}
```

Но я захотел его протестировать и всплыла проблема с тестированием двух последних случаев: Из `"сегодня, 14:41"` и `"вчера, 14:41"`. И если я напишу обычный юнит тест то он будет работать только сегодня а завтра уже не будет...

Помогите пожалуйста:

```
@Test
public void whenThen() throws ParseException {
    final TimeConverter converter = new TimeConverter();
    final Timestamp today = converter.convert("сегодня, 14:41");

    //... завтра при запуске "сегодня" будет иметь уже другое значение...
}
```

Что делать в такой ситуации?

Comment: в таких ситуациях использую инъекцию зависимости, а не статическую зависимость как у вас.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman вы spring имеете в виду?

Comment: я не имел ввиду какой-либо фреймвор. я говорил про метод -
 Dependency Injection.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman что-то много очень разной информации о вариантах что под этим понимается или может это все об одном просто я еще этого не понял... Не поясните немного, может ссылку на статью какую нибудь, что-бы было понятно о чем речь?

Comment: используйте `this` там где это несет какую-то полезную информацию, в противном случае вы ухудшаете читаемость кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляете инъекцию в ваш класс

```
public class TimeConverter {
    /**
     * Formatter for types "28 мар 17, 14:29".
     */
    final private SimpleDateFormat format;
    final private Calendar current;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public TimeConverter() {
        this.format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm");
        current = new GregorianCalendar();
    }

    // конструктор с инъекцией 
    public TimeConverter(SimpleDateFormat format, Calendar calendar) {
        this.format = format;
        this.current = calendar;
    }

    /**
     * Converting datetime in Timestamp.
     * @param data for converting.
     * @return same datetime how Timestamp object.
     * @throws ParseException if the beginning of the specified string
     *            cannot be parsed.
     */
    public Timestamp convert(final String data) throws ParseException {

        if (data.contains("сегодня")) return this.todayConverter(data);

        if (data.contains("вчера")) return this.yesterdayConverter(data);


        return new Timestamp(this.format.parse(data).getTime());
    }

    /**
     * Converter for types how : "сегодня, 14:41".
     * @param data String value for convert.
     * @return datetime how Timestamp object.
     */
    private Timestamp todayConverter(final String data) {

        final String[] time = getTime(data);

        current.set(
                current.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                current.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                current.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                parseInt(time[0]),
                parseInt(time[1]));


        return new Timestamp(current.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    /**
     * Converter for types how : "вчера, 14:41".
     * @param data String value for convert.
     * @return datetime how Timestamp object.
     */
    private Timestamp yesterdayConverter(final String data) {

        return new Timestamp(todayConverter(data).getTime() - 86_400_000L);

    }

    /**
     * Get time from string with time and data.
     * @param data for parse.
     * @return array where by 0 index = hours, by 1 index = minutes.
     */
    private String[] getTime(final String data) {

        final String[] arr = data.split(" ");

        return arr[1].split(":");
    }
}
```

И в тестах используете

```
public class TimeConverterTest {
    @Test
    public void whenThen() throws Exception {
        // вы можете сделать нужный вам calendar
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        final TimeConverter converter = new TimeConverter(
            new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm"),
            calendar
        );
        final Timestamp today = converter.convert("сегодня, 14:41");
    }
}
```

Вместо реальных объектов в тесте можно использовать **mock** и будет даже проще.

Comment: Я понял просто добавить еще конструктор в котором можно подменить текущее время, тогда и проблема с понятием сегодня пропадает.

Answer (score 2):

В чём проблема сгенерировать аналогичный Timestamp в тесте? Используйте Calendar, как это сделано у вас в классе, и сравните получившиеся Timestamp'ы

Comment: и что будет тестироваться в таком случае? Что метод при одинаковых входящих данных дает одинаковый результат? Все таки хотелось бы проверить что метод дает верный результат, не было бы смысла в нем если бы он давал одинаковый но неверный результат. К тому же на самом деле при генерации `Timestamp` секунды всегда разные при одинаковых параметрах... я же их не задаю в шаблоне `SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy, HH:mm")` Так что `equals()` будет `false`.

Comment: @Павел поскольку во входящих данных вы задаете только дату, часы и минуты, ваш `Timestamp` либо не должен содержать остальных компонент (секунд и миллисекунд), либо они не должны использоваться (и, соответственно, отсекаться в тесте).

Comment: @andreycha звучит убедительно, но все равно не понятно как мне получить это образцовое значение, так что бы не получился еще код который тоже надо отдельно тестировать. С чем мне мой `.convert("сегодня, 14:41")` сравнивать?

Comment: @Павел если под образцовым вы подразумеваете значение с точностью до миллисекунды, то никак. Значение с точностью до минуты можно получить так же, как вы это сделали в своем классе.

Comment: @andreycha да нет миллисекунды это как раз не принципиально. Но если это отбросить то какие тут варианты?

Comment: @Павел вам уже дважды ответили -- используйте такой же код для получения текущей даты и нужного времени, как и в самом классе. Тестовый код иногда может повторять тестируемый код, это нормально.